# Custom Class not displayed in the dropdown Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, class, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController and a custom ViewController Custom Class which I added to the project. However when I go to set the 'Custom Class' property on the view-controller in Storyboard my custom class does not show up on the list.

Looking at my new header file the file is named "ViewController+SecondViewController.h"
I have tried renaming the file to SecondViewController.h but the custom class is still not displayed.
Checked that it is correctly a subclass of ViewController
Compiled program just to make sure xcode was working with latest information.
Restarted xcode. Restarted my Mac Book. Deleted DerivedData. Typed in the name of the new view controller but the I can not still connect to the new custom class. What would cause my class to not show up in the 'Custom Class' drop down? Is there something different with Xcode 7.2.1 and how the new customer class is named. I have made other custom classes before Xcode 7.2 and never saw the named being displayed asViewController+SecondViewController and never had an issue with custom classes being displayed.

Comment: ViewController+SecondViewController is this your classname?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue by renaming my "ViewController+SecondViewController.h" to"SecondViewController.h" and"SecondViewController.m"